# Groupby list within the list using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have two classes:

```
class Customer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public List<Order> OrderList { get; set; }
}

class Order
{
    public string OrderNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Using LINQ, i want to get list of Orders group by ZipCode. If Zipcode "12121" has 10 customers and each has 2 orders then it should return me only one Zipcode with the list of 20 orders.

I am trying to do it like this but not able to figure out whats wrong

```
var orders = br.CustOrderList
.Select(r => new
{
    r.ZipCode,
    r.Name,
    r.OrderList
})
.GroupBy(x => new { x.ZipCode, x.OrderList});
```

Any help please?

Comment: Could you please provide. How you want input and expected output

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
var orders = br.CustOrderList
    .GroupBy(x => x.ZipCode)
    .Select(g => new
    {
        ZipCode = g.Key,
        Orders = g.SelectMany(x => x.OrderList)
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var orders = br.CustOrderList
.Select(r => new
{
    r.ZipCode,
    r.Name,
    r.OrderList
})
.GroupBy(x => x.ZipCode);
```

You just want to group by the ZipCode so just group by that

Ah yea just try

```
var order = br.CustOrderList
              .GroupBy(x = x.ZipCode);
```

No need to select new items out of the list

Comment: this just returns Zipcode. I also want list of Orders for that Zipcode